# How do I undo changes made on Drupal 7 website?

Tags: php, web, drupal-7

Although I have more than 15 years experience in web development, I must admit that I am new to Drupal. I am beginning to understand the concept, but I am still having problems with some basic questions that I haven't been able to find the answers yet.

At work, I have "inherited" a site that was built in Drupal 7, and the management wants me to make some functional and content changes/additions on the existing site. If I had a chance to do it "by hand", that wouldn't be a problem. But, it is my understanding that everything must be done the Drupal's way or no way. I don't want to break the site while still learning Drupal.

I would like to know how I can actually undo changes done on the live site - like in case I have already saved them and later realize I screwed something up?

I would also like to make the exact copy of the live site and move it to the local server (XAMPP). Do I use MIGRATE for that? Does it matter that my local Drupal is 7.39 version, and the live Site runs 7.35 ?

Comment: Yes, versions matter. Take an exact copy of all files and the database and install them locally.

Comment: what do you mean, "changes"? changes to the content of a page? that's not programming - that's "how to use drupal". changes to some custom code in drupal? that's another matter...

Comment: @MarcB in some cases there will be changes to the content, yes. But, I will have to change layout, add new pages, blocks, views etc.

Comment: oh who cares, I'll figure it out myself